# how to pass variable into .js file

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal

Is there any way to pass variable "userID" into the imported file "file.js?"

```js
<script>

  var imported = document.createElement('script');
  var = userID;
  imported.src = 'https://website.com/file.js';
  document.head.appendChild(imported);

</script>
```

Comment: I doubt there is a way to do this like this.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/4482/15055

Comment: "var = userID;" is a problem. If you want to declare the variable only: "var userID;" As written, you're not declaring a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not entirely sure that i understand what you are trying to do, but perhaps a global variable is the most straight forward approach?

You could do

```
<script>

var imported = document.createElement('script');
// var = userID;
window.userID = 1234;
imported.src = 'https://website.com/file.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);

</script>
```

And then in your imported file you can reference

```
window.userID // -> 1234
// or even just
userID // -> 1234 - though i would use the window.userID to at least be explicit
```

I guess another more complicated way were to ajax the js file's content and replace some placeholder with id before appending it to the page.
And btw only ever insert a js file unto your page like this if you truly trust its origin.

Would that solve your problem?